# Angular Text Rotator

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation, text-rotation

I want to implement simple text rotator which will rotate each 3 seconds some texts. The change will be animated.

I have found jquery plugin which perfectly solves my problem:
https://github.com/peachananr/simple-text-rotator

But I have read that it's not a good practice to use jquery plugins in Angular Applications. Hence I want to implement text rotator in 'Angular way'. But I don't know how to do it.

Is there an easy way to implement such text rotator using Angular 2+?

---

EDIT:

The functionality should work like this:
Let's say I have heading text.
I want that each 2 sec **the heading text will change** (to another sentence from some predefined set of heading sentences).
This change should be animated.

Comment: As in it spins? The github demo isn't working for me.

Comment: For me github demo is working. No it shouldn't spins. The functionality should rotate sentence to another (from some predefined set of sentences). This change should be animated.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I can't deduce what you are asking for. Rotate != spinning, then what?

Comment: You can view demo here: http://peachananr.github.io/simple-text-rotator/demo.html. I didn't say anything about spinning text. What I mean is to rotating text/word and switch to another text/word - from predefined set of words.

Comment: Rotate is a synonym for spin. I viewed that demo (mentioned earlier) and I see no animations. Just the text "Super Simple, Customizable, Light Weight, Easy Text Rotator with Style" over and over again, in different colors.